# Бот не хочет отправлять или принимать сообщения

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Не понимаю, то ли бот не принимает сообщения, то ли не хочет отправлять их. Подскажите пожалуйста где я ошибся.

````
    @bot.message_handler(content_types='text')
    def inner_messages(message):
        santas.append(message.text.lower())
        kids.append(message.text.lower())
        print(santas)
        if message.text.lower() == "все":
            for i in santas:
                santa = rd.choice(santas)
                kid = rd.choice(kids)
                if Santa == kid:
                    santa = rd.choice(santas)
                    kid = rd.choice(kids)
                print(Santa + ': ' + kid)
                bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, santa + ': ' + kid)```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. может не происходит вызов функции bot.send_message, так как ваши условия не выполняются
2. Вызов функцию bot.send_message(1, "santa:child"), не доставляет сообщение в чат